# How to make my tags inside the input element

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

The tag items are appearing above the input element but I'd like them to be inside the input element. I've included the jQuery code and CSS. Can someone give me advice?

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('tags-input'), function(el) {
      let hiddenInput = document.createElement('input'),
        mainInput = document.createElement('input');
      tags = [];

      hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', el.getAttribute('data-name'));
      mainInput.setAttribute('name', 'tag');
      mainInput.setAttribute('id', 'tag2');
      mainInput.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Contoh: akreditasi, banding, TUK mandiri')
      mainInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
      mainInput.classList.add('main-input');
      mainInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
        let enteredTags = mainInput.value.split(',');
        if (enteredTags.length > 1) {
          enteredTags.forEach(function(t) {
            let filteredTag = filterTag(t);
            if (filteredTag.length > 0)
              addTag(filteredTag);
          });
          mainInput.value = '';
        }

      });

      ...
```

```css
.tags-input {}

.main-input {}

.tags-input .tag {
  font-size: 85%;
  padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
  margin: 0.25em 0.1em;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.tags-input .tag .close::after {
  content: 'x';
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 0.75em;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: (1.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tags-input .main-input {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
...
<div class="field">
  <label>Tag</label>
  <div class="tags-input" data-name="tags-input">

  </div>
  ...
```

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle, or post complete code

Comment: @AkhilAravind here's the full code https://jsfiddle.net/zadmy3vr/

Comment: Share here the full code. Your snippet is not working. In the fiddle is also not working

Comment: @MihaiT https://jsfiddle.net/zadmy3vr/

Comment: It looks like you are attempting something similar to the "add tag" feature found here on Stack -  but if you inspect the HTML with the developer tools you will notice that the tags do not get added within the `input` element itself but within a `div` element that has some clever css positioning applied to make it appear as you wish. Perhaps I misunderstood however.

Comment: Personally I think it looks better *above* the input field the way you have it now.  More room for tags without shoving the input way over to the right, which would be awkward. This is a case where I think the trickiness and "coolness" factor works against the usability and isn't worth it. Just my opinion.

Comment: By the way, jquery plugin [select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox) does this exact thing, so you might want to consider using it instead of coding your own.

Comment: @RamRaider is right. An input field is a widget generated by internal browser code that is only designed to hold text and manages the input process, and you have no access to that internal functionality. Naturally the CSS layout by default is going to try to prevent items from overlapping so if you want to force an unnatural overlap you're going to have to carefully manage the position. An overlay (div over the input field) is the most likely reasonable way to do it.  But is it really worth it? Then you also have to add the complexity by determining the size of the tags

Comment: ... and somehow adjust the cursor input position to start just after the end of the last tag. I like tricky stuff like that, but you should carefully think about the the complexity versus benefit tradeoff. And remember you have to maintain it across multiple popular browsers and it has to stand the test of time. Do you really want to be maintaining and possibly debugging that code for the rest of your life? Old saying in engineering: KISS. (Keep It Simple Stupid).